# react-google-maps not showing on screen

Tags: google-maps, reactjs

i have a react app and i am integrating google map using react-google-maps. It fetches data of lat and lng using node server.

Map.js

```
import { withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker } from "react-google-maps";
import React from 'react';

// Wrap all `react-google-maps` components with `withGoogleMap` HOC
// and name it GettingStartedGoogleMap
export const GettingStartedGoogleMap = withGoogleMap(props => (
<GoogleMap
ref={props.onMapLoad}
defaultZoom={3}
defaultCenter={props.centre[0]}
 onClick={props.onMapClick}>
{props.markers.marker.map((marke, index) => (
  <Marker
    {...marke}
    onRightClick={() => props.onMarkerRightClick(index)}
  />
))}
</GoogleMap>
));
export default GettingStartedGoogleMap;
```

Layout.js

```
//some imports
const calculate = (x)=>{
var lt=0;
var lg=0;
var count=0;
x.marker.map((k,i)=>(
lt+=k.position.lat,
lg+=k.position.lng,
count++
))
var centre=[{lat:lt/count, lng:lg/count}];
return centre;
};

export const Layout = props => (

//some div and other elements working fine witout map
     <div id="map"><GettingStartedGoogleMap
   containerElement={
     <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />
   }
   mapElement={
     <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />
   }
   centre={()=>calculate(props.restraun)}
   onMapLoad={_.noop}
   onMapClick={_.noop}
   markers={props.restraun}
   onClick={_.noop}

 /></div>
    //other elements
);
export default Layout;
```

Maps is not shown in front end. I have included script tag with api key. Tried changing height from % to fixed value. But still doesn't work.

Data is of format

```
restran:{
          marker:[
                  {position:
                            {lat:'value',
                             lng:'value'
                            }
                    key:'value'
                   }]}
```

data is being shown correctly if printed on console from node

Edit 1: It seems to be error with the component itself as i was able to print some text instead of markers.

Comment: set the width of div with the id of "map" and it should be able to render it.

Comment: did that but still doesn't show up @Ozan